# Regular Expression for comma separated names

Tags: regex, string-parsing

Regular comma separated names would be easy to use regular expressions on, but my problem is: how would a regular expression distinguish between a list of names and a (last name, first name)?

This is the example I have:

```
Lawrence, Billy
Alex Newell, Jess Glynne, DJ Cassidy, Nile Rodgers
```

These are some examples of many that show up in a text file that I have and I need to distingush between them. Does anyone have a solution?

I thought about just counting the commas and distinguishing that way, but I also have examples like this:

```
Tisto, Sean Kingston & Flo Rida
```

This is the format (a list of artists), just to give you an idea of what I need in the end:

```
Lawrence, Billy
Alex Newell
Jess Glynne 
DJ Cassidy
Nile Rodgers
Tisto
Sean Kingston
Flo Rida
```

Comment: Do you control the generation of the file? I'd encapsulate the strings before using the delimiter. Also you should stick to one delimiter `,` or `&`.

Comment: The generation of the file is from a db of artists of a song track. So, techincally, yes, but I don't control if there is a ',' or a '&' @chris85

Comment: The generator doesn't have output options though? You're going to have issues with names like `Bill & Belle Reed`.

Comment: Now you see my headache haha @chris85

Comment: These are how the artists have their names on the song track, so it is how it is.

Comment: Isn't the DB structured though? `Artist`, `Song`, `Album`, etc. I don't see a way you could accurately do this with a regular expression.

Comment: The DB is structured in that way, but the artist field is still as shown above on each line. How would I get just (word, word)? I tried (\w+, \w), but it does this for every case. @chris85

Comment: Are `lastname, firstname`s on their own lines or could they be mixed in?

Comment: Lastname, first name will never be mixed in. It will always be on its own line

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier to parser you could add some constraints. For example, you could make every ones names two phrase and when you don't ether one of the word you could add a phrase as a filler. So then, when you parse the file every to phrase is a name. Then your delimiters are ' ', ',' and '&'